# Is it possible to remove certain elements from a vector based on the information from another vector?

Tags: c++, vector, containers

Lets say we have the vectors A and B which
contain objects not primitive data.

The B vector would contain information about which elements to
be removed from the vector A. I don't want to rely on index if possible.

I suspect that in Java this could be done with a method call
to removeAll where you pass the list of things to be
removed as an argument.

Is this possible with the C++ language?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of information? Can you give an example?

Comment: Anything is possible :D

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but you'd need to give a bit more information about the specifics of what is in A and B in order to get a good answer to this question.

Comment: vector A and B contains what primitive data types or objects ?

Comment: Fair enough! Vector A contains a list of entities in the world e.g. tiles, bullets, players and such. If a bullet hits a tile for example i want it to be removed from the list of entities. That bullet i want to register in the vector B which later on will compare to the vector A and verify that here's something that needs to be removed.

Comment: @Dizeme So all you need is a design approach, as of now your question has nothing to do with `C++` or even `std::vector`. Or else show something what you tried, where you're stuck or the errors/issues you're facing

Answer (score 5):

If the vectors are sorted, you can make use of `std::set_difference`. In fact of you don't sort them first you can't get better than n^2 in terms of complexity. So my suggestion is: sort the vectors and use set_difference.

Comment: Use forward_list for better sorting speed.

Comment: @lucas92: Not likely.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing the specifics of what `A` and `B` contain, it is possible to do something like this:

```
std::vector<int> A;
std::vector<int> B;
// fill in your vectors
A.erase(std::remove_if(A.begin(), A.end(), [&](int i)
{
    return std::find(B.begin(), B.end(), i) != B.end();
}), A.end());
```

This will search `B` for anything that matches in `A`.  If something is found, it will be removed.

Answer (score 2):

This process can be decomposed into:

1) Choose the comparison method that qualifies an element to be deleted,

2) Find a way to delete the selected elements (either as a continuous range or one by one).

Why should this be a problem at all? You only have to find a way to compare the elements on vector B with the elements on vector A, and based on that, you build a list of the elements to be removed, and then you remove them.

Your vector, of course, could be a vector of some class, which contains all the properties you need to do the comparison between the objects in A and B.